# Editing Torah on Tisha B'av

Tags: halacha, torah-study, tisha-bav, employment, publications

Is it a violation of the prohibition to learn Torah on Tisha B'av to edit a Torah publication?

The intent of the editor is not to learn, but it ends up happening automatically if he is editing something that he hasn't learned before.  On the other hand, perhaps editing Torah content would not bring the happiness of learning Torah which is the root of the prohibition.

Comment: I don't think so because of the reason you mentioned. I recall a rebbi in camp half-jokingly telling me "You, davka, *should* learn on Tisha b'av."

Comment: Any reason for the downvote?